# Experiencing Classpath Error

Tags: java

```
 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.naming.NamingException;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Hashtable;

 public class QueueSend
 {
   public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

if (args.length != 1) {

System.out.println("Usage: java examples.jms.queue.QueueSend WebLogicURL");

return;

}

  InitialContext ic = getInitialContext(args[0]);
}

 private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException
  {
    System.out.println("url is "+url);      
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
  } 
}


 javac -cp wlthint3Client.jar QueueSend.java
```

Creates `QueueSend.class`

```
 java -cp wlthint3Client.jar QueueSend t3://localhost:7001
```

Says

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot 
 instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exc
 tion is 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]
```

Then i checked the jar file

```
 javap -cp wlthint3client.jar weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
```

It shows

```
 Compiled from "WLInitialContextFactory.java"
 public class weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory implements    
  javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory {
   public weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory();
   public final javax.naming.Context   
   getInitialContext(java.util.Hashtable)     throws 
   javax.naming.NamingException;
 }
```

How do i solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the current directory to the runtime classpath

```
java -cp wlthint3Client.jar;. QueueSend t3://localhost:7001
```

`java` doesn't include the current path when the `-cp` flag is used so this needs to be added explicitly

Comment: If this isn't running on windows, change the classpath separator from  `;` to `:`.